# How to save folds in Vim after changing the foldmethod to diff?

Tags: vim, neovim

I make heavy uses of folds in my VIMRC file (init.vim since I'm on neovim), and I also make use of the tool `fugitive.vim`.

When I want to do a diff on it, it changes to the fold method to `diff`. Pretty useful in the moment. But when I want to go back to my previous folds I find them all gone (`set foldmethod=manual`) and then have to refold everything. How can I revert back to my manual folds after `fugitive` does a diff on them?

I've tried going through the help files and to look online but I cannot find out how to do it.

Comment: `:h fold-manual` mentions `:mkview` and `:loadview`. Have you given it a try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:h fold-manual` mentions `:mkview` and `:loadview`, which can save the folds and then restore them.